# How to prepare my data for SVM classifier in matlab

Tags: machine-learning, svm, matlab, libsvm

I am new to SVM and Matlab. I would like to have an example how to prepare my data to be as input to the SVM classifer (using libsvm)

let us assume that i have a group of words 
first i have extracted some attributes such as bigram and trigrams (Average Jaccard index) and I wanted to input these values to a classifier in order to classify them

I know that i have first to train my classifier with initial data (labled) I have these data

60000 words from dictionary and 40000 other terms 
while I generate 100000 random strings

now i want to classify if the new words are random or not

I have calculated the Jaccard index for each one and also i have calculated some other features such as number of characters and number and some other features.

now how I can convert these data to metrix ? I am a bit confused about the next step

Comment: See my question over there.. if need help i can provide code as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792576/libsvm-java-implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the answer in LIBSVM Frequently Asked Questions http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#/Q03:_Data_preparation

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit older, but as a new learner to SVM as well, did you ever find a good resource for how to prepare datasets for svm reg or classification?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.